# Read new data from file and display it on html page

Tags: python, python-3.x

On my Raspberry Pi I've built a script that reads data from a file and shows a live video stream.

The content is then displayed on an html page:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
temperature=f.read()
f.close()
print(temperature)
PAGE="""\
<html>
<body>
<center><img src="stream.mjpeg" width="640" height="480"></center>
<center><h2>%s</h2></center>
</body>
</html>
""" %(temperature)
```

My problem is, that the file is being updated every 10 minutes - how can I reload or pull the new content from the file each time I access the html page?

Since I'm streaming video, the script runs all the time so I can't stop it and run it again to get the most updated data from the file.

Please advise

Comment: Well when someone accesses the page you update the file BEFORE rendering the page, then you render it. I think you need a webserver there, something like flask/django?